# Grafico de Barras con seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Hola quiero hacerun grafico de barras para contar el acceso de internet por cada 100 hogares a lo largo de los años. El tipo de columnas que tengo son estas:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 864 entries, 0 to 863
Data columns (total 7 columns):
 #   Column                        Non-Null Count  Dtype  
---  ------                        --------------  -----  
 0   Año                           864 non-null    int64  
 1   Trimestre                     864 non-null    int64  
 2   Provincia                     864 non-null    object 
 3   Accesos por cada 100 hogares  864 non-null    object 
 4   Unnamed: 4                    0 non-null      float64
 5   Unnamed: 5                    0 non-null      float64
 6   Unnamed: 6                    0 non-null      float64
dtypes: float64(3), int64(2), object(2)
```

Y a la hora de graficar me sale un : `TypeError: agg function failed [how->mean,dtype->object]`
aqui les pongo el codigo:

```
datos_agrupados = df6.groupby('Año')['Accesos por cada 100 hogares'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.barplot(x=datos_agrupados.index, y=datos_agrupados.values, color='skyblue')
plt.xlabel('Años')
plt.ylabel('Acceso por cada 100 hogares')
plt.title('Accesos por cada 100 hogares a lo largo de los Años')
plt.show()
```

---

Despues de todo eso quize cambiar la columna a tipo (int) para ver si eso me solucionaba pero a la hora de hacerlo la columna Accesos por cada 100 hogares, se convierte en datos NAN, les comparto el codigo.

```
 df6['Accesos por cada 100 hogares'] = df6['Accesos por cada 100 hogares'].astype(int)

df6['Accesos por cada 100 hogares'] = pd.to_numeric(df6['Accesos por cada 100 hogares'], errors='coerce')

datos_agrupados = df6.groupby('Año')['Accesos por cada 100 hogares'].mean().sort_values(ascending=False)

plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
sns.barplot(x=datos_agrupados.index, y=datos_agrupados.values, color='skyblue')
plt.xlabel('Años')
plt.ylabel('Acceso por cada 100 hogares')
plt.title('Accesos por cada 100 hogares a lo largo de los Años')
plt.show()
```

Alguien ahi me puede instruir? gracias...

Comment: El error es exactamente el que tratas de corregir,  `Accesos por cada 100 hogares` es de tipo `object` (seguramente `str`), el error se debe a intentar aplicar la media sobre ella. Debe ser de tipo int, el problema con los NaN es dificil de discernir su causa sin ver un ejemplo de los datos originales de esa columna, seria de mucha ayuda si pudieras agregar esta informacion. Si quietas el errors='coerce' te deberia generar una excepción con información relevante sobre los NaN. Por ejem., una causa típica es parsear números que usan como separador de miles/decimal algo distinto a tu locale.